# Is there any attempt to standardize a "cancel" action in elevator buttons?

Tags: usability, buttons, physical, toggle

I live in a country where only a few (I've heard of 2 or 3) elevators has the option to toggle back a pressed button in order to cancel the request. Of course, I'm waiting for all elevator buttons everywhere to become toggleable some day...

Are there any standards regarding this, worldwide or national?

Comment: I certainly hope so, but so far doesn't seem to be happening

Comment: What would happen if you clicked floor 4 and then unclicked it. WHERE SHOULD YOU GO? I just imagine the elevator opens to a black abyss.

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of a [question asked 2 years ago.](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/19612/why-dont-most-elevator-panels-let-you-unselect). Also, [a column in Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2012/06/15/why-dont-elevators-allow-you-to-toggle-whether-they-stop-at-a-floor/) about this question.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato - huh! nice thought. maybe you can't cancel a request until you push another button. i'm actually gonna go on a ride in such an elevator next week. i'll let you know what happens in such a case :)

Comment: @user1757436 thanks! nice post, and i didn't find it when i looked up similar questions before posting..

Answer (score 7):

It's not a good idea. Many people will find this useful, but few will be annoyed. I guess you're thinking that pressing floor "2" once will light up the button, pressing again will cancel it and turn off the backlit. Here's a problem:

Elevators are used by everyone, old people, **blind people**, kids, conveying the information that the button for a particular floor is already pressed or not **in a way that everyone understands in just a second** isn't an easy task. **Visually impaired who use braille** on those buttons will not be able to tell. People not familiar with this backlit on off design may misunderstand it easily.

It'll be way too annoying if the lift doesn't stop where intended. A lift occasionally stopping at an extra floor is way better than a lift that occasionally **skips the desired floor** out of misunderstanding.

Comment: well concluded, a lift that occasionally skips the desired floor *would* be too annoying. i've been struggling with this question ever since i was about five years old :) thanks man.

Comment: although, regarding that people "won't be able to tell" - how about going back to basics and bringing back those *push buttons* - you press them in order to instruct the elevator on the desired floor, and they could *pop out* once the elevator had reached that floor. if you regret - simply depress them. this would be a perfect compromise, in my opinion.

Comment: Let's go back to the actual problem: an elevator button was pushed erroneously.  The need isn't to cancel, but rather not to encounter the problem in the first place.  Looking at it that way, how can the button panel be designed to reduce the number of erroneous presses while still meeting its needs in terms of serving everyone?

Comment: The consideration of something new been annoying, strange, etc happens all the time, that's how we get used to new things, isn't? Now, back to the question, if you are in your house/building, and you have a few floors, it's not too bad if somebody presses an extra button, but when you are in a hotel, and kids press many buttons, or somebody forgets their floor, or decides to go down with their friend at a different floor, etc, is really annoying and time consuming for the rest of the people on the elevator

Comment: @nadyne - It's not rational (*and* bad practice) to design interfaces that make it harder for a user to interact with just to patch up a fundamental problem in the design. The need here **is** to cancel rather than not encountering the problem. You can't (and **shouldn't**) prevent people from making mistakes, you're better off granting them a way out (i think you'll find [*Never Use A Warning When You Mean Undo*](http://alistapart.com/article/neveruseawarning) quite interesting).

Comment: I'm **still** convinced, though, that this **can** be implemented successfully, e.g. with *push buttons*, *double-click* to cancel, *dynamic braille* indication, *voice narration*. Or just all of the above :)

Comment: Elevators are microprocessor controlled these days, push buttons popping out by themselves would be awkward. Voice narration has same probs as visually impaired (and **language barrier**). And I've seen people banging the buttons 5 times even, their intuition tells them pressing many times will make the lift move faster, so forget double tapping.

Comment: Yes sometimes it is a must have feature, and people who care enough for this do find a way. Am not saying there should not be a standard, but doing this elegantly is a problem much harder than it appears and not many people want this. That's why there has not been a standard for this. Of course the world would be a better place if someone works for an economical, intuitive and error free way, but this is not a very lucrative field to spend years upon, so no one gives a damn.

Comment: I didn't say that the design should be harder to interact with, I only questioned whether there could be a better design that would reduce erroneous button pushes.  Reducing errors does not mean harder to use.

Comment: REQUESTING a stop is a far more important & common operation than CANCELING a stop. The former should be easy and single-push (as it is). The latter need not be as simple a UI. In fact, canceling a stop is not an essential operation (obviously — we’ve lived this long without it). Therefore, some users (blind, perhaps) might not have as easy access to it. A fairly easy-to-understand UI would be to have a separate button labeled “Cancel Stop.” When pushed, it engages a cancel mode, which

Comment: ...causes all requested stop buttons to blink. Buttons pushed in this mode would be cancelled. To disable cancel mode, push the “Cancel Stop” button again, or simply wait N seconds for the mode to auto cancel (N=3 would be a good place to start). The advantages of a UI like this are many. The price for mistakes is low. The UI is inviting and fairly self-explanatory. And it automatically turns itself off if you get lost.

Comment: Instead of selecting the floor to go to, instead you could press stop when it reached your floor. The elevator could gong for the 10's columns and ding for the 1's so 32 would be gong gong gong, ding ding and then you would press the only button on the elevator which is stop. Elevators already start with an established direction.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato, this is anywhere between exaggerated and preposterous - do you expect people to be **alert** all the way up (or down), tapping at the *exact* moment their floor is reached? what about very *fast elevators*? what about *elevators packed with people*? plus, elevators *don't start with an established direction* (assuming no earlier call was made) - they go where you tell them.

Comment: @PatomaS: now imagine those kids on that same elevator with other people, but the elevator has a "cancel stop" feature. How annoying would it be if those kids canceled your stop as you were going up and you had to either get off at some floor above and try to catch another elevator back down to your floor, or wait for it to finish going ALL THE WAY up to wherever the last (legitimate) passenger was going, and then ride it ALL THE WAY back down to your floor?